# Problem with changing class variables' value

Tags: c++, c++11, opengl

I have a problem. I'm working on a OpenGL project and I need to access a class variable by the class method. I got it done, but then changed some code and now it's not working and i cannot get it done. It's all about `Yaw` and `Pitch` variables. If i change them in their class method (e.g. `ProccesMouseInput`) they don't change their values, but I had already tried it in main function and then they do... Here's my code.

Camera.h

```
#pragma once
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <glm/vec3.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>

enum class movement_direction{
    FORWARD,
    BACKWARD,
    LEFT,
    RIGHT,
    UP,
    DOWN
};

class Camera {
private:
    glm::vec3 m_Position;
    glm::vec3 m_Front;
    glm::vec3 m_Up;
    glm::vec3 m_Right;
    glm::vec3 m_WorldUp;
    float m_MouseSensitivity;
    float MovementSpeed = 2.5f;
    float MouseSensitivity = 0.1f;
    float FOV = 45.0f;
    float Yaw;
    float Pitch;


public:
    Camera(glm::vec3 pos, glm::vec3 up, float yaw, float pitch);
    Camera(float PosX, float PosY, float PosZ, float UpX, float UpY, float UpZ, float yaw, float pitch);
    void ProcessMouseInput(float offsetX, float offsetY, bool constrainPitch);
    void ProcessKeyboardInput(movement_direction direction, float deltaTime);
    void ProcessScrollInput(float offsetX, float offsetY);
    void UpdateCameraVectors();
    glm::mat4 GetViewMatrix();
};
```

Camera.cpp

```
#include "Camera.h"
#include <iostream>



Camera::Camera(glm::vec3 pos = glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f), glm::vec3 up = glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f), float yaw = -90.0f, float pitch = 0.0f)
    : m_Position(pos), m_Up(up), m_WorldUp(up), Yaw(yaw), Pitch(pitch), m_MouseSensitivity(MouseSensitivity)
{

    UpdateCameraVectors();
}

Camera::Camera(float PosX, float PosY, float PosZ, float UpX, float UpY, float UpZ, float yaw, float pitch)
    : m_Position(glm::vec3(PosX, PosY, PosZ)), m_Up(glm::vec3(UpX, UpY, UpZ)), m_WorldUp(glm::vec3(UpX, UpY, UpZ)), Yaw(yaw), Pitch(pitch), m_MouseSensitivity(MouseSensitivity)
{

    UpdateCameraVectors();
}

void Camera::ProcessMouseInput(float offsetX, float offsetY, bool constrainPitch = true)
{
    Yaw += offsetX * m_MouseSensitivity;
    Pitch += offsetY * m_MouseSensitivity;
    if (constrainPitch)
    {
        if (Pitch < -89.0f)
            Pitch = -89.0f;
        if (Pitch > 89.0f)
            Pitch = 89.0f;
    }

    UpdateCameraVectors();

}

void Camera::ProcessKeyboardInput(movement_direction direction, float deltaTime)
{
    float velocity = MovementSpeed * deltaTime;

    if (direction == movement_direction::FORWARD)
        m_Position +=  m_Front * velocity;
    if (direction == movement_direction::BACKWARD)
        m_Position -= m_Front * velocity;
    if (direction == movement_direction::LEFT)
        m_Position -= m_Right * velocity;
    if (direction == movement_direction::RIGHT)
        m_Position += m_Right * velocity;
    if (direction == movement_direction::UP)
        m_Position += m_WorldUp * velocity;
    if (direction == movement_direction::DOWN)
        m_Position -= m_WorldUp * velocity;
}

void Camera::ProcessScrollInput(float offsetX, float offsetY)
{
}

void Camera::UpdateCameraVectors()
{
    glm::vec3 direction;

    direction.x = cos(glm::radians(Yaw)) * cos(glm::radians(Pitch));
    direction.y = sin(glm::radians(Pitch));
    direction.z = sin(glm::radians(Yaw)) * cos(glm::radians(Pitch));

    m_Front = glm::normalize(direction);
    m_Right = glm::normalize(glm::cross(m_Front, m_WorldUp));
    m_Up = glm::normalize(glm::cross(m_Right, m_Front));
}

glm::mat4 Camera::GetViewMatrix()
{
    return glm::lookAt(m_Position, m_Position + m_Front, m_Up);
}
```

Application.cpp

```
/* Including GLEW */
#include <GL/glew.h>

/* Including GLFW */
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

#define STB_IMAGE_IMPLEMENTATION
#include "vendor/stb_image/stb_image.h"

#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/type_ptr.hpp>

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <conio.h>

#include "Shader.h"
#include "Camera.h"

void processInput(GLFWwindow* window);
void mouse_callback(GLFWwindow* window, double xpos, double ypos);
void scroll_callback(GLFWwindow* window, double offsetX, double offsetY);

const int SCR_WIDTH = 800;
const int SCR_HEIGHT = 600;

float deltaTime = 0.0f;
float currentFrame = 0.0f;
float lastFrame = 0.0f;

float lastX = SCR_WIDTH / 2;
float lastY = SCR_HEIGHT / 2;

bool firstMouse = true;

float fov = 45.0f;

Camera main_camera(glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, -3.0f), glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f), -90.0f, 0.0f);

int main(void)
{

    GLFWwindow* window;

    /* Initializing the library */
    if (!glfwInit())
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to initialize GLFW.\n";
        return -1;
    }

    /* Creating a windowed mode window and its OpenGL context */

    window = glfwCreateWindow(SCR_WIDTH, SCR_HEIGHT, "Hello World", NULL, NULL);

    if (!window)
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to open GLFW window.\n";
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }

    /* Making the window's context current */
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK)
        std::cout << "Failed to initialize GLEW\n";

    glfwSetInputMode(window, GLFW_CURSOR, GLFW_CURSOR_DISABLED);
    glfwSetCursorPosCallback(window, mouse_callback);

    glfwSetScrollCallback(window, scroll_callback);

    /* Getting the version of GL */
    std::cout << "Using GL Version: " << glGetString(GL_VERSION) << std::endl;

    float vertices[] = {
        -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,    0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,    0.0f, 0.0f,
         0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,    0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,    1.0f, 0.0f,
         0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,    0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,    1.0f, 1.0f,
         0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,    0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,    1.0f, 1.0f,
        -0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,    0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,    0.0f, 1.0f,
        -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,    0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,    0.0f, 0.0f,

        -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,    0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,    0.0f, 0.0f,
         0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,    0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,    1.0f, 0.0f,
         0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,    0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,    1.0f, 1.0f,
         0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,    0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,    1.0f, 1.0f,
        -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,    0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,    0.0f, 1.0f,
        -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,    0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,    0.0f, 0.0f,

        -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,    0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,    1.0f, 0.0f,
        -0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,    0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,    1.0f, 1.0f,
        -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,    0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,    0.0f, 1.0f,
        -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,    0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,    0.0f, 1.0f,
        -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,    0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,    0.0f, 0.0f,
        -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,    0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,    1.0f, 0.0f,

         0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,    0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,    1.0f, 0.0f,
         0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,    0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,    1.0f, 1.0f,
         0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,    0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,    0.0f, 1.0f,
         0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,    0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,    0.0f, 1.0f,
         0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,    0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,    0.0f, 0.0f,
         0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,    0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,    1.0f, 0.0f,

        -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,    0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,    0.0f, 1.0f,
         0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,    0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,    1.0f, 1.0f,
         0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,    0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,    1.0f, 0.0f,
         0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,    0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,    1.0f, 0.0f,
        -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,    0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,    0.0f, 0.0f,
        -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,    0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,    0.0f, 1.0f,

        -0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,    0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,    0.0f, 1.0f,
         0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,    0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,    1.0f, 1.0f,
         0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,    0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,    1.0f, 0.0f,
         0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,    0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,    1.0f, 0.0f,
        -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,    0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,    0.0f, 0.0f,
        -0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,    0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,    0.0f, 1.0f
    };

    glm::vec3 cubes_positions[]{
        glm::vec3( 0.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f),
        glm::vec3( 2.0f,  5.0f, -15.0f),
        glm::vec3(-1.5f, -2.2f, -2.5f),
        glm::vec3(-3.8f, -2.0f, -12.3f),
        glm::vec3( 2.4f, -0.4f, -3.5f),
        glm::vec3(-1.7f,  3.0f, -7.5f),
        glm::vec3( 1.3f, -2.0f, -2.5f),
        glm::vec3( 1.5f,  2.0f, -2.5f),
        glm::vec3( 1.5f,  0.2f, -1.5f),
        glm::vec3(-1.3f,  1.0f, -1.5f)
    };


    /* VERTEX ARRAY */
    unsigned int VAO;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
    glBindVertexArray(VAO);

    /* VERTEX BUFFER */
    unsigned int VBO;
    glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    /* VERTEX LAYOUT */
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8 * sizeof(float), (void*)0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8 * sizeof(float), (void*)(3 * sizeof(float)));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);

    glVertexAttribPointer(2, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8 * sizeof(float), (void*)(6 * sizeof(float)));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);

    /* LOADING TEXTURES */
    // --- first texture object ---
    unsigned int texture1;
    glGenTextures(1, &texture1);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture1);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_BORDER);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_BORDER);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);

    float borderColor1[]{
        0.1f, 0.1f, 0.0f, 1.0f
    };
    glTexParameterfv(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_BORDER_COLOR, borderColor1);

    int width, height, channelsNr;
    unsigned char* data = stbi_load("res/textures/container.jpg", &width, &height, &channelsNr, 0);
    if (data)
    {
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
        glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to load texture\n";
    }
    stbi_image_free(data);

    // --- second texture object ---
    unsigned int texture2;
    glGenTextures(1, &texture2);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture2);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_BORDER);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_BORDER);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);

    float borderColor2[]{
        0.1f, 0.1f, 0.0f, 1.0f
    };
    glTexParameterfv(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_BORDER_COLOR, borderColor2);

    stbi_set_flip_vertically_on_load(true);
    data = stbi_load("res/textures/awesomeface.png", &width, &height, &channelsNr, 0);
    if (data)
    {
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to load texture\n";
    }
    stbi_image_free(data);

    /* BINDING BEFORE THE DRAW CALL */
    // --- shader ---
    Shader basic("res/shaders/Basic.glsl");
    basic.Bind();
    basic.SetUniform1i("texture1", 0);
    basic.SetUniform1i("texture2", 1);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    // --- texture ---
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture2);

    // --- vertex array object ---
    glBindVertexArray(VAO);

    float value = 0.5f;
    basic.SetUniform1f("mix_value", 0.2f);

    /* Loop until the user closes the window */
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        currentFrame = (float)glfwGetTime();
        deltaTime = currentFrame - lastFrame;
        lastFrame = currentFrame;

        processInput(window);

        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        glClearColor(0.f, 0.2f, 0.2f, 1.f);
        /* Render here */

        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture1);

        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture2);

        glm::mat4 projection = glm::perspective(glm::radians(fov), (float)SCR_WIDTH / (float)SCR_HEIGHT, 0.1f, 100.0f);
        basic.SetUniformMatrix4fv("proj", 1, glm::value_ptr(projection));

        glm::mat4 view = main_camera.GetViewMatrix();
        basic.SetUniformMatrix4fv("view", 1, glm::value_ptr(view));

        for (int i = 0; i < (sizeof(cubes_positions) / sizeof(glm::vec3)); i++)
        {
            float angle = 20.0f * i;
            glm::mat4 model = glm::mat4(1.0f);
            model = glm::translate(model, cubes_positions[i]);
            model = glm::rotate(model, glm::radians(angle), glm::vec3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
            basic.SetUniformMatrix4fv("model", 1, glm::value_ptr(model));

            glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 36);
        }

        /* Swap front and back buffers */
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);

        /* Poll for and process events */
        glfwPollEvents();

    }

    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}

void processInput(GLFWwindow *window)
{
    if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE) == GLFW_PRESS)
        glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, true);

    if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_W) == GLFW_PRESS)
        main_camera.ProcessKeyboardInput(movement_direction::FORWARD, deltaTime);
    if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_S) == GLFW_PRESS)
        main_camera.ProcessKeyboardInput(movement_direction::BACKWARD, deltaTime);
    if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_A) == GLFW_PRESS)
        main_camera.ProcessKeyboardInput(movement_direction::LEFT, deltaTime);
    if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_D) == GLFW_PRESS)
        main_camera.ProcessKeyboardInput(movement_direction::RIGHT, deltaTime);
    if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_SPACE) == GLFW_PRESS)
        main_camera.ProcessKeyboardInput(movement_direction::UP, deltaTime);
    if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_LEFT_CONTROL) == GLFW_PRESS)
        main_camera.ProcessKeyboardInput(movement_direction::DOWN, deltaTime);
}

void mouse_callback(GLFWwindow* window, double xpos, double ypos)
{
    if (firstMouse)
    {
        lastX = (float)xpos;
        lastY = (float)ypos;
        firstMouse = false;
    }

    float offsetX = (float)xpos - lastX;
    float offsetY = lastY - (float)ypos;
    lastX = (float)xpos;
    lastY = (float)ypos;
    main_camera.ProcessMouseInput(offsetX, offsetY, true);
}

void scroll_callback(GLFWwindow* window, double offsetX, double offsetY)
{
    fov -= (float)offsetY;
    if (fov < 1.0f)
        fov = 1.0f;
    if (fov > 90.0f)
        fov = 90.0f;
}
```

Comment: Could you please provide a minimal reproducible example instead of asking to fix your code?

Comment: Some clarification please: _" If i change them in their class method "_ - you mean `Camera::ProcessMouseInput`? _"but if I do it in main function they do"_ - What does that mean? I can't see a line where you do that (and you can't since both are private). Maybe the problem is in the constructor. The checks: `if (Yaw != newYaw)` and `if (Pitch != newPitch)` are logically wrong and lead to UB since those members have not been initialized to any value before.

Comment: where exactly are you changing the yaw value?

Comment: where do you call the method? How do you know that the members didnt not change?

Comment: 'ProccessMouseInput' is called in `mouse_callback` defined in main whenever the mouse moves. I've assigned it at the top of the main function (`glfwSetCursorPosCallback(window, mouse_callback);`). What's more constructor doesn't matter (but thanks for pointing out that assigning `Yaw` to `newYaw` there is logically wrong - I'll fix it). The value of `Yaw` and `Pitch` changes in `ProccessMouseInput`.

Comment: I'm assuming it's something to do with including the header file into cpp files. But I can't fix it.

Comment: You're comparing to members with indeterminate values in the second constructor. This has undefined behaviour. Use the initialiser list, like you do in the first one.

Comment: Fixed it. Unfortunately didn't help, but thanks for trying.

Comment: Looks like it's time to attach a debugger and check what values `ProcessMouseInput` is receiving. I'm still a bit confused where the values change and where they don't, sorry if I miss something, it's quite a bit of code. I see only one call to `ProcessMouseInput` in `mouse_callback`. That way it works, right? And which call does not work?

Comment: Yeah, `ProccessMouseInput` is called only in `mouse_callback`, but at the top of the main function I'm calling `glfwSetCursorPosCallback(window, mouse_callback);` and it calles `mouse_callback` every time you move your mouse.

Answer (score 1):

I finally fixed it! It was something to do with multiplication of `offsetX` and `offsetY` by `m_MouseSensitivity`. For some reason it wasn't initializing right and thus was assigned to 0. By multiplying by zero you get zero so `Yaw` and `Pitch` didn't change. Thank you for  the help <3